# Apps must containt a proviosining profile / Profile does not include the selected signing certificate

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode9, provisioning-profile

I added my profile and certificate to xCode. Now when I try to upload my app, first I chose "Automatic signing".

Then I got two errors: unknow error, length: [some number] and "apps must contain a provisioning profile in a file named embedded.mobileprovision".

So I chosed next time "Manual signing". Now when I try to choose a provisioning profile, I am getting: "Profile does not include the selected signing certificate".

Am I supposed to install also the provisioning profiles or private keys in some way or...? I have pre-generated all of them on Linux.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Import the certificate private key into the Keychain app then restart the Xcode. It's well known that latest imported certificate or a provisioning profiles can be unseen by Xcode.

Comment: Thanks. Your solution might work. I already generated the build from the command prompt.